# How is with-command of oracle used in HQL

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hql, common-table-expression

There is a query that I use with command for avoidance of duplication query in where clause. There is a simplified of it as below:

```
with with_table as
 (select id from table1 where [ statemenet ])
select *
  from table1 e
 inner join table2 w
    on e.id = w.table1_id
 where e.id in (select id from with_table)
   and w.table1_id in (select id from with_table)
```

I want to do such in hql.
How do I do?
How do I do if there is no way as same as with-command.
**Note:** When I drop with-command and duplicate the query in where clause, the response time of query is twice, so i do not want to drop it. How is it done in hql.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this specific case: unless I'm wrong, leave it "as is", just remove the last line in your query. Why? Because you're joining E and W tables by

```
e.id = w.table1_id
```

but only for those IDs that exist in WITH_TABLE. So, if E.IDs are in there and W.TABLE1_ID is joined to E.IDs, W.TABLE1_IDs also exist in the WITH_TABLE.

Comment: I know but it is a simple. I mean how do we use with-command in hql

Comment: I'm sorry, I wouldn't know; that's why I said "Regarding this specific case". To be honest, today I've learned something new, thanks to you: "HQL" - never even heard of it before (what an ignorant, eh?). I hope someone else will be able to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could convert it into an `INNER JOIN`

```
select *
  from table1 e
 inner join table2 w
    on e.id = w.table1_id
 inner join (select id from table1 where [ statement ] ) c
   on e.id = c.id
where w.table1_id = c.id;
```

Comment: I know but because of some reason else i need to use with

Comment: @rezaramezanimatin : Does your Hive/hql version support `WITH` clause?

Comment: @rezaramezanimatin : If it does not support `WITH` clause, then why not try the JOIN syntax? or if it supports, why not try using it?

Comment: I want to use with because of some reason. One of them is query performance. If you get more info, get me to talk online chate

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. You can't do that in HQL.

JPQL and HQL provide a simple subset of the SQL standard, hence you need to use SQL for complex queries.

You can use the Hibernate [`ResultTransformer`](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-use-the-hibernate-resulttransformer-to-customize-result-set-mappings/) to map the incoming `Object[]` array to entity graphs.

Comment: I want to know what it is that such this command is not able to be in HQL. For example with-command and union and so on

Comment: First, because WITH is not supported by all databases. Second, because HQL is meant to fetch entities not generate reports. Third, HQL is not meant to replace SQL.